# Extracting data from website to excel error

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, extract

I am having a difficulty setting up data extraction from website to Excel.
I want to extract exact price of a product to excel.
So far I have this code:

```
Sub GetData()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer  'Microsoft Internet Controls library added
    Dim itemEle As Object
    Dim data As String
    Dim y As Integer

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate "https://www.nay.sk/samsung-ue55nu7172"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    y = 1

    For Each itemEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("price")
    data = itemEle.getElementsByClassName("price")(0).innerText
        y = y + 1
    Next
    data = Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

What would you suggest?

Comment: I write it directly using developer mode in excel enabling VBS and writing it directly there - so yes, Alt+F11

Comment: I see. Then it is VBA, not VBS.

Comment: Are you after just one price? Every price? Do you need any meta information to go with the price info?

Comment: I just need the one price: Cena v predajni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub GetData()

    Dim objIE As New InternetExplorer   'Microsoft Internet Controls library added
    Dim itemEle As Object
    Dim data As String
    Dim y As Integer

    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate "https://www.nay.sk/samsung-ue55nu7172"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    y = 1

    For Each itemEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("price")
        Cells(y, 1) = itemEle.outertext
        y = y + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

This is what you get:

[image]

To get the correct properties of the `itemEle`:

- put a stop sign on the line from the printscreen below
- select `itemEle` with your mouse
- press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works. Can you please explain, how to only get the price "CENA V PREDAJNI" to excel?

Comment: @robsik - try the Shift + F9 and look for the corresponding class.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want every price?

You can list the first two for example this way:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, i As Long, html As New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.nay.sk/samsung-ue55nu7172", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
    Dim titles As Object, prices As Object
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set titles = .querySelectorAll(".title")
        Set prices = .querySelectorAll(".price")
    End With
    For i = 0 To 1
        Debug.Print titles(i).innerText & prices(i).innerText
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

That loop returns you these:

[image: data]

---

You actually have all the elements on the page with a `price` class stored in the object `prices`.

You can view all the prices by looping the length of that object/nodeList with:

```
For i = 0 To prices.Length - 1
    Debug.Print Prices.item(i).innerText
Next i
```

Likewise you can loop the `.Length` of `titles` but note that it is a different length from `prices`. There are more prices on the page (or rather elements with a `price` class versus elements with a `title` class.

---

**References (VBE>Tools>References):**

1. HTML Object Library

Comment: Another great solution! I think all the web-scraping request should be routed to you :-) just kidding.

Comment: After the solution you gave to the file upload which is one of the best I have seen on SO.......